# Ajuda em Java: Arrays

Tags: java, array, algoritmo

Exercício:

> Fazer duas listas de nomes na forma de arrays, comparar quantos nomes da Lista 1 estão na Lista 2, e depois calcular a porcentagem destes, sobre a porcentagem do total das pessoas da Lista 2.

Segue o código que já fiz:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalourosDoadores {

    public static void main (String args []) {

        System.out.println ("Escreva os Nomes na Primeira Lista: ");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        String [] lista1 = new String [];

        System.out.println ("Escreva os Nomes na Segunda Lista: ");

        String [] lista2 = new String [];


        System.out.println (calcularLista (lista1, lista2));
    }

        public static double calcularLista(String lista1[], String lista2[]) {

            int cont = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i<lista1.length;i++) {

                if (lista1[i].equals(lista2[i])) {

                    cont++;
                }

            }

            return cont/lista2.length;
        }
}
```

Por gentileza, alguém pode me ajudar a terminar?

Comment: Qual a dúvida que está tendo?

Comment: Está dando problemas na execução do Algoritmo.
Na hora de colocar a quantidade de nomes.
Eu queria colocar um while(hasNext()), mas não sei como colocar, e nem onde.
Pode verificar, e fazer com que o Algoritmo execute?

Comment: Qual problema? Seja mais especifico em onde está ocorrendo e qual o problema que está ocorrendo.

Comment: Por gentileza, você pode me ajudar a executar este Algoritmo?
Está dando problemas que está faltando a dimensão do Array. Queria colocar o while(hasNext()).
E mesmo se colocar as dimensões das Listas, dá o:
java.lang.nullPointerException

Comment: O erro já te deu a solução, informe a dimensão do vetor quando inicia ele. Ex.: `String[] meuVetor = new String[6]` onde 6 é a dimensão.

Comment: Mesmo colocando as dimensões, dá o erro de java.lang.nullPointerException.
Por gentileza, podes ajudar?

Comment: Se você também me ajudar colocando exatamente a pilha de erros e em qual linha ocorre o erro na pergunta, sim.

Comment: Certo. A IDE fala que dá erro nessa linha:
if (lista1[i].equals(lista2[i])) {
E dá erro nessa linha:
System.out.println (calcularLista (lista1, lista2));

Erro de java.lang.nullPointerException

Comment: Você não preencheu nenhum indice, por isso da erro de nulo. Quando o laço percorre os indices, todos estão nulos.

Comment: Eu coloquei:
String [] lista1 = new String [3];

E

String [] lista1 = new String [5];

É isto o que você quer dizer?

Se for isto, dá exatamente este erro.

Comment: Em que momento do código você usa o scanner para preencher as listas? No código você não está preenchendo nenhuma das duas listas, só está iniciando elas.

Comment: Certo, e como se usa o Scanner em Arrays?

Comment: Faz um ``for`` iterando em cada posição dos arrays depois de instanciados e dimensionados, e em cada posição deles você usa esse objeto Scanner que você inicializou e faz isso: ``lista1[i] = sc.nextLine();``. E não se esqueça de fechar o Scanner, com ``´sc.close()``.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro que seu algoritmo não define em momento algum o tamanho dos vetores, antes de usá-los, você deve definir o tamanho de cada um:

```
//neste exemplo iniciei os 2 vetores com o tamanho 4 indices
String [] lista1 = new String [4];
String [] lista2 = new String [4];
```

Depois, você precisa usar um laço para poder preencher os vetores, respeitando o limite de tamanho de cada um:

```
System.out.println ("Escreva os Nomes na Primeira Lista: ");

for(int i = 0; i < lista1.length; i++){
    lista1[i] = sc.nextLine();
}

System.out.println ("Escreva os Nomes na Segunda Lista: ");

  for(int i = 0; i < lista2.length; i++){
    lista2[i] = sc.nextLine();
}
```

Segundo a lógica dita na pergunta, há um problema no seu método `calcularLista`, ele não está contando e nem efetuando a operação corretamente.

Você precisar percorrer as duas listas para checar quais indices que a lista1 possui em comum com a lista2, e parar a execução do segundo laço quando for encontrado um nome identico nas duas listas:

```
for (int i = 0; i<lista1.length;i++) {

    for(int z = 0; z<tamanhoLista2;z++){

        if (lista1[i].equals(lista2[z])) {

            cont++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Com isso, o método vai comparar cada indice da lista1 com cada indice da lista2 e contar apenas quando forem achados iguais nas duas listas.

E pra calcular a porcentagem, você precisa dividir o resultado dos itens encontrados multiplicado por 100, pelo tamanho da lista2, mas antes precisa transformar um dos valores para double, no exemplo, eu transformei o tamanho da lista2 em double:

```
  public static double calcularLista(String lista1[], String lista2[]) {

        int cont = 0;
        double tamanhoLista2 = lista2.length;

        for (int i = 0; i<lista1.length;i++) {

            for(int z = 0; z<tamanhoLista2;z++){

                if (lista1[i].equals(lista2[z])) {

                    cont++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return (cont * 100)/tamanhoLista2;
    }
```

Veja seu código todo funcionando no [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/wuedTJ).

Comment: Executando o código no ideone, dá erro de: "error: reached end of file while parsing". Por qual motivo?

Comment: @InicianteemJava aqui está executando normalmente, sem erro algum, estranho isso. Testei nos 3 navegadores que tenho e nenhum deu esse erro.

Answer (score 3):

Seu algoritmo tem alguns probleminhas. O primeiro é o seguinte:

```
String [] lista1 = new String [];
```

Quando você cria o array, você deve especificar qual é o comprimento dele. Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
String[] lista1 = new String[10];
```

Porém, você pode dizer que 10 é muito... ou talvez pouco... ou talvez você deva pedir para o usuário quantos são. Aliás, você não está pedindo para o usuário digitar nada, está apenas escrevendo no console sem ler nada de lá.

Assim sendo, para ler um número do console:

```
System.out.print("Escreva quantos nomes há na primeira lista: ");
int tamanhoLista1 = sc.nextInt();
```

Com isso você pode criar os arrays:

```
String[] lista1 = new String[tamanhoLista1];
```

E então, você faz o mesmo com a lista 2. O enunciado do seu exercício não deixa claro se as duas listas necessariamente têm o mesmo tamanho ou não. Mas se não tiverem, você pode fazer o tamanho a lista 1 ser diferente do tamanho da lista 2.

Falta também ler os nomes. Para ler um nome, você pode fazer isso:

```
String nome = sc.nextLine();
```

Ou então, já ler direto para dentro do array:

```
nome[i] = sc.nextLine();
```

E no caso daí de cima, você talvez queira saber de onde vem esse `i`. A resposta é que você vai precisar ler cada uma das listas de nomes usando um `for` e este `i` será a variável indexadora desse `for`.

Já na hora de comparar as listas, você está comparando o elemento 0 de uma lista com o 0 de outra lista. O 1 de uma lista com o 1 da outra lista. O 2 de uma lista com o 2 da outra lista... Mas isso não é o que você quer! Por exemplo, imagine este caso:

> Lista1: Alberto, Fernanda, Marcelo, Rodrigo, Maria, Tatiana
>   Lista2: Joaquim, Carlos, Maria, Adriana, Fernanda, Marcelo, Alberto

Quantos nomes da lista 1 estão na lista 2? A resposta correta é 4 (Alberto, Fernanda, Marcelo e Maria). Porém o seu algoritmo não irá achar nenhum desses nomes, porque as posições deles não coincidem.

Para resolver isso, recomendo fazer uma abordagem diferente. Você vai precisar criar dois laços `for` um dentro do outro. O de fora percorrendo a lista 1 e o de dentro percorrendo a lista 2, de forma a ir comparando todos os elementos de uma lista com todos os elementos da outra lista. Ao achar um elemento que coincida, você faz o `cont++;` e dá um `break;`. O `break;` é importante, porque uma vez que o elemento da lista 1 for encontrado, você não vai querer continuar procurando (e se continuar, vai ter problema com listas que tenham elementos repetidos).

Por fim, um último detalhe:

```
return cont/lista2.length;
```

Aqui `cont` é inteiro e `lista2.length` também é inteiro. Assim sendo, será realizada uma divisão inteira. Somente após a divisão inteira ser efetuada é que o valor será convertido para um `double` para ser retornado. Isso não é o que você quer também, mas a solução é fácil:

```
return ((double) cont) / lista2.length;
```

Isso vai te dar um número entre 0 e 1. Como você quer porcentagem, multiplique por 100:

```
return ((double) (cont * 100)) / lista2.length;
```